# General solution of the partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To be honest I'm a bit lost on this, and I would like to get a hint or something that can help me, thanks. I need to find the general solution of the next equation:

$$x_1u_{x_1} + · · · + x_nu_{x_n} = cu$$

I know that most sure exists a change of variable that would help to solve the equation, but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ and $c$ constants?  I guess $c$ is a constant but the $x_i$ are (non-constant) coordinate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide throughout by $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2}$, the left hand side becomes the radial derivative of $u$, since it is a dot product of $\nabla u$ with the unit radial vector at $x$). The solutions are radial and the equation satisfied by $u(r)$ is (well, I am keeping the name of the function to avoid the messy notation):
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{cu}{r}
$$
which is an ordinary equation for $u(r)$:
$$
\frac{du}{u}=c\frac{dr}{r}.
$$
It easily integrates to

$$
\ln u=c\ln r+A
$$
where $A$ is a real constant. Therefore,
$$
u(r)=Br^c
$$
where $B>0$.$B=0$ also works.